# SSRS Load testing and pure performance

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am doing load testing with an SSRS report and getting more and more disappointed with it.
I need an expert opinion whether there is a way to improve performance.

Environment setup:

1. SSRS Report which calls stored procedure that selects from table with 5000 rows, runs 3 milliseconds top.
2. C# Application which based on input parameters creates threads and in parallel makes calls to the SSRS Report.
3. SSRS is accessed by `POST` request to the URL and under one NT User.

Stats:

- Stored procedure in MSSM Studio runs 3 milliseconds
- SSRS report in IE runs for 50ms
- C# Application with single thread gets results back in 157 - 239 milliseconds
- 4 threads average 500 milliseconds for the same report
- 8 threads: 800 milliseconds for the same report.
- 16 threads: 1300 milliseconds for the same report.

Is there any configuration or settings that can be changed so SSRS handles concurrent calls better?

Comment: Are any of the SSRS caching options usable for you? Caching the report would be fastest, but if you can't do that, caching the dataset would probably help.

Comment: Caching take the same time to run, it looks like there is something else wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the RS service only has 2 threads available per CPU. I've seen that number touted in various forums around the net, [here is one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/br/sqlreportingservices/thread/83c32b84-88a4-433e-83a8-60dacbee7267).

You may find that the threads you are attempting to fire up are actually hindering the performance, effectively 'overloading' the RS threads. You can check your log file to see if threads are being stressed [according to this](http://performancepointblog.com/2008/06/sql-reporting-services-what-does-that-thread-pool-pressure-warning-mean/), and states you can expect an error of the following type in the log:

> WARN: Thread pool pressure. Using current thread for a work item

Perhaps you could look at matching the number of max concurrent threads you are creating to the `number of CPUs the RS service has access to * 2`